# Arrangement, Skipping and URL re=writing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I tried to re-write on my own but unable to do so, basically, I want to re-write php-based URL with .htaccess but also need to skip few parameters of php URL for example;

**Original URL:**
http://example.com/details.php?id=62?title=billions-s01e09-webrip-x264-fumettv

**Required Format:**
http://example.com/billions-s01e09-webrip-x264-fumettv-id62.html

**Format Sequence:**
MySiteURL/Title-of-Post-PostID.html

Looking for kind response, please guide me how can i make this possible through .htaccess.
waiting for kind response...
Good day

Answer (score 2):

As you already know that you have to change the .htaccess file in your server. You can use regx to achieve your required url. Using the following code can help you.

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-id([0-9]+).html?$ details.php?id=$2&title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

worked fine for me. Hope will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite

- http://example.com/foobar-id123.html

to

- http://example.com/details.php?id=123?title=foobar

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-id([0-9]+)\.html$ /details.php?id=$2?title=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks "starkeen" for your answer but you share rule to convert .html link into php but i requested to guide me how to write .php url into html as quoted in my question, mate

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add **.html** to the pattern. Anyway try the updated rule.